# Content displayed with [col=200]

Tags: joomla-3.x

I transferred my Joomla website from one server to another server and updated to joomla3. On inner pages, the sidebar menu content is displaying appended junk text `[col=200]`.

How to remove  **[col=200]** ?

Screenshots:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a link to the site so we can check the source code of the page?

Answer (score 1):

Have you also updated all third party extensions?

These look like shortcodes which will have been added for a third party plugin, rather than part of core Joomla behaviour, and so a Joomla 3 patch may have been released (assuming it was working before you updated to Joomla 3).

A quick Google suggests that the menu may be Maximenu, in which case there is a suggested solution here:  https://forum.joomlack.fr/index.php/4-maximenu-ck/7222-column-width-text-in-submenu

> 1/ use maximenu for the second menu, then the params will be removed
>
> 2/ use the plugin maximenu params to set your menu, then you will not
>   need anymore the [xxx] text into your menu links

Instructions for using maximenu are here: https://www.joomlack.fr/en/joomla-extensions/maximenu-ck